# Fluentd – how to scan log files under different folders?

Tags: fluentd

Question 1 : – how to scan log file from different folders ?
Question 2 : - also how can we use the wild char in log file name ?

e.g. 
folder\folder1\catalina.92ca.2019-01-07.log
folder\folder1\catalina.92ca.2019-01-06.log
folder\folder2\catalina.567c.2019-01-07.log
folder\folder2\catalina.567c.2019-01-06.log

I tried something like this, which didn't work.

path /var/Logs/folder/*/catalina.*.%Y-%m-%d.log

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my Linux box :

path /var/Logs/folder/*/catalina.*.%Y-%m-%d.log